# Editing a single line in a large text file

Tags: python, text-files

So I need to record a set of 4 integers whose values are different for every second of the day. i.e.:

```
#Here the values are initialized to the same value, however they will change as samples are taken
data = [[.25 for numData in range(4)] for numSecs in range(86400)]
```

Now obviously a two dimensional array(gah its python, LIST) whose first index length is 86400 is quite impractical.  Instead I want to create a text file with 86400 lines formatted as such:

```
numSec data0 data1 data2 data3

0 .25 .25 .25 .25
1 .25 .25 .25 .25
2 .25 .25 .25 .25
...
```

And as samples are taken, I want to be able to edit this file, nay, I want to be able to edit the line of the file whose numSec = the second the sample was taken.  For example, a sample taken at numSec = 2 (2 seconds after midnight)  would cause my program to edit the file so that:

```
0 .25 .25 .25 .25
1 .25 .25 .25 .25
2 .70 .10 .10 .10
...
```

Seems easy enough, I have even read a bunch of posts which demonstrated how to rewrite a single in a text file.  The problem is, they all require that you read in the whole file.  I don't want my program to be reading 86,400 lines every second.

Thus we arrive at my question:  Can I read a single line in a text file, edit it, and write it back to the file, without reading the entire file every single time a change needs to be made?

P.S. I should note I am running Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) and this is for use in a ROS node

P.P.S This program will be running for an arbitrary amount of days so each "second" of data could be read and rewritten many times.  Also another reason I would like to use a file is if the system needs to be shut off, I would like to save the distributions for the next time it is run.

Comment: If each entry in the file has fixed length, maybe `mmap`. Else, consider database.

Comment: If each entry has a fixed length, you _can_ just open the file in binary mode, calculate the offset, `seek`, and `write` in place. (This will actually work in text mode too, as long as you take into account newlines and char widths, but it's technically illegal.) However, `mmap` is probably going to be simpler, so +1 to jokester.

Comment: What makes you think that storing 86400 sets of 5 numbers is a problem? In any event, you need to write, on average, half of the file every second.  Also, each second will be dealing with the line immediately following the previous line - why not keep everything in memory?

Comment: How often is the data accessed after writing? And does the instance stay alive? If so, cache it to a list and save every x updates to the file. If you don't want to go with `mmap` or a database.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If every second you update the file with the new four-pair value, why dont you just append to the file the data received in every second? After midnight, reset the file to zero. When reading, you assume that all seconds above the last second read, are the initialized value. You avoid initialization, and your file size is lower until the end of the day.

Comment: Do need to write in the "past"? I mean, do you ever need to write to line 2 after you wrote to line 3?

Comment: @jokester, I can make them fixed by using placeholder zeros, if necessary.

Comment: @Neil, It justs seems like its a lot, if its not really then I guess no problem.

Comment: @sebastian I'm sorry I wasnt clear, this will actually be updated every day, its tracking probabilities of an event at certain times of a day.

Comment: Are you stuck in that file format? I mean, why don't save only relevant data and you process later assuming missing 'seconds' lines? Saving I/O calls seems to be your goal.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you really want a 2D array, have you considered using numpy or pandas instead of native `list`s of `list`s? In general, things will be a little more convenient to operate on, a lot faster, and more compact. In particular, writing a 86400-row array won't require any looping in Python—of course it will still require a 2MB I/O, but that will probably be nearly instant thanks to disk caching, and require almost no CPU.

Comment: @Sebastian I am not stuck in any particular format, I have never dealt with large quantities of data and for some reason I thought text files might be a good way to deal with that.

Comment: @abarnert I have never heard of numpy or panda, nor do I know what disk caching is, but I will do some reading and see if that will help me.

Comment: If your intent is to save I/O calls in real time processing, I'll suggest to store only relevant data, that is, the second and the four-pair values. Then, process the file in order to elaborate, possibly another file, for example, to feed it to a plot program. Processing will read each line setting a default value for every missing second in the file. But all depends on your needs.

Comment: The second and the four pair values are the only relevant data, as you said.  The goal is to have a four-pair value for every single second of the day, so although what you suggest would save a lot of time and space in the beginning, as the file becomes richer I will still run into the same problem.  I highly appreciate your suggestion though, I hadn't thought of that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to modify this a bit and it assume that all lines are of the same length. For this, I had to pad the first column to a fixed width. But if you don't want padding you should be able to calculate the number of 1,2,3,4,.. digit numbers before a particular row.

```
data = [[.25 for numData in range(4)] for numSecs in range(86400)]
length_line=0

def write_line(f, sec, data):
    line="{:6d}".format(sec) + " " +" ".join(
            ["{:.2f}".format(dd) for dd in data])+"\n"
    f.write(line)
    return len(line)

with open('output', 'w') as of:
    for i,d in enumerate(data):
        length_line=write_line(of, i, d)

with open('output', 'rb+') as of:
    # modify the 2nd line:
    n = 2
    of.seek(n*length_line)
    write_line(of, n, [0.10,0.10,0.10,0.10])
    # modify the 10th line:
    n = 10
    of.seek(n*length_line)
    write_line(of, n, [0.10,0.10,0.10,0.10])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, While I am having some trouble decyphering write_line (don't worry I'll figure it out) I see you still are declaring the two dimensional array.  The problem of read/writing is to avoid that structure, thus including makes the use of read/write unnecessary.  I guess I have a new question, is 86400 sets of 5 numbers really not that big of a space hog?

Comment: @RoboCop87, I declared it just to populate the output file for testing. You don't need a 2d array at all. But you need to write out an initial file. That structure should use less than 10MB though.

Comment: I'm not sure if your familiar with ROS (I'm definitely not, and I'm supposed to be using it) but from what I understand it runs a lot of programs at the same time and is very taxing on your system.  I'm not sure how much 10MB impacts a system like that, which is why I was trying to be cautious by using the file.  Would it be barely a blimp in the scope of computing? Or would it make a difference?

Comment: I think you'll be fine with checkpoints to a file at 5 minute intervals with an in memory data structure if you are not running on an embedded system. It may even be better to keep appending to a file and starting a new file each day.

Comment: Also the database idea is pretty solid

Comment: *My ignorance* I thought using the text file in this way WAS using a database, database being a collection of data and a populated text file being a collection of data

Comment: No, a database is so much more than that. You will not need to write code to deal with files, and you can do all kinds of updates reliably.

Comment: I will look into that more then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the lines are of different lengths, then everything after the modified line will be in the wrong position and you have to rewrite all those lines.  If the lines all have the same length, then you can `seek()` and `write()` the new data by calculating the line's offset in the file.  See [Python File Objects](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it useful to store 345600 (86400 * 4) times a 0.25. Just store the default in the first line. Than append one line at a time. If the time stamps do not come in order just put them in as they are and after the day is over sort the file content once and fill the missing time stamps with the default. Example:

```
default: 0.25
2 .70 .10 .10 .10
3 .80 .20 .20 .20
1 .50 .30 .30 .30
5 .40 .30 .30 .30
```

Later process this file to get this:

```
1 .50 .30 .30 .30
2 .70 .10 .10 .10
3 .80 .20 .20 .20
4 .25 .25 .25 .25
5 .40 .30 .30 .30
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, however this program will be running for an arbitrary amount of days so simply appending one at a time would not be an effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use a sqlite database to store records. The key would be the second of the observation and each row would consist of 4 values.
Updating and editing would be much more efficient.