# Creating and using databases

Tags: database

So the solid consensus I got from the answers to this question: [Editing a single line in a large text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034895/python-editing-a-single-line-in-a-large-text-file)

was that instead of using a text file I should create a database and store my data there.  While I think this is a great idea, I don't know the first thing about databases, the programming languages used for databases, or how to use a database once I have set it up.  Could you guys give me a shove in the right direction and point me an absolute noob tutorial that might help me with this?

UPDATE:  Hey guys, so I was looking at mySQL and there are a whole bunch of versions!  The Cluster CGE looks like the best one, and it says it is good for "real-time open source transactional database designed for fast, always-on access to data under high throughput conditions" which just about hits the nail on the head of what I need.  It says commercial next to it though, so I don't know if I would have to pay some god awful fee for it.  I tried it anyway, and it said I should have gotten a license already, and until I did I could only use it for 30 days.  Im confused...

Can I get this version for free? If so, where do I get the license?
Is this version way overpowered for what I need?  I need:
1. A storage medium through which I can store large amounts of data
2. Read and write from in real time with simultaneous access
3. Have two different "keys" (I think I'm using that right, I need to be able to search for entrees based on one of two criteria).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is a great choice, given your Python flair.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html

Good luck!

Comment: I wouldn't say it is so much of a flair as I am forced to use it!  I much prefer C++, but circumstances...Thank you!

Comment: Well, MySQL also has a value proposition over other databases.  It's hard to beat free.

Comment: I see this tutorial keeps mentioning servers, clients, and mostly stuff I am not dealing with (I don't think).  My only goal is to share large amounts of information between two python programs.  Is this still the way I should go?

Comment: Yes.  Each of your python programs is a client.  The DB itself is a server.  Those terms are really dependent on context.  What is a "server" to one part of your application is a "client" to another.  For example, your web application calls back to your web server, so in that context your web app is the client and your web server is the server.  But the web server calls the database to get information, so in that context the web server is a client of the DB and the database is a server.